# Ubuntu: keyboard and mouse not working (Mac)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, mouse, liveusb

-Ubuntu 16.04.4
-(Mac)
-(Live USB with persistence)
-(Created with UNETBootin)

First boot, the home screen shows up and i see the cursor at the center of the screen but nothing works (neither mouse or keyboard).

I read online that they forgot to install the package during the update or something like this, but I don’t really know how to fix it!

Can someone help...?

Comment: The answer seems to be here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin, but i’m not an expert and before messing up something i preferred to ask here.

Comment: Well, you discovered a potential answer on [ubuntu.se], wouldn’t it be better to ask there?